# Erro na emulação do app no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

quando eu vou emular o aplicativo pelo AVD no android studio, ele aparece essa mensagem, assim que clico no botão para "Inicializar o dispositivo Virtual"

"Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined"

Não sei o porque disso estar acontecendo. Alguém pode me ajudar pfv. 
Valeu.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, ou em que momento acontece, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Comment: Tente deletar o seu emulador e recriar ele de novo